# Do I have to start a HTML document in VS code with doctype?

Tags: html

I created a file called 'index.html' on Visual Studio Code. I believe the application already knows the code I will be writing is 'html'. Must I still start off my document with `<<!DOCTYPE html>` ? Please see below

````
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html> ```

Thanks
````

Comment: If you want to comply with HTML5 standards, yes.

Comment: Yeah doctype should be declared everytime

Comment: When in doubt HTML Boilerplate it out

Comment: @zer00ne That's not his question. His question asks if he needs to fill that in using Visual Studio or will VS fill it in for him.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** have doctype in an HTML document. It is not for the code editor, but rather the browser. Vs Code **will not** automatically add doctype for you.

As W3Schools says:

> *'The declaration is not an HTML tag. It is an "information"* to the browser about what document type to expect.'
>
> [See article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

The quickest way to setup an HTML file in VS code is with the emmet shortcut Shift+1 [See emmet cheat sheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: That's not his question. His question asks if he needs to fill that in using Visual Studio or will VS fill it in for him.

Comment: @Rob - I updated my question to also cover that question. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't explicitly *have* to add a DOCTYPE, but you *should*.

The DOCTYPE is **not explicitly required**, though the browser will go into [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) if the DOCTYPE is omitted. This means that HTML5 tags such as `<article>`, `<header>`, `<nav>` and `<section>` will fail to render correctly. These tags are almost exclusively used for [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles).

Additionally, most browsers (and even IDEs) these days are smart enough to infer what DOCTYPE you are using, and will inject it automatically for you. Still, you should not *rely* on this, and should endeavor to add it yourself.

Comment: That's not his question. His question asks if he needs to fill that in using Visual Studio or will VS fill it in for him.

Comment: [A DOCTYPE is a required preamble.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#the-doctype)